# What's a good Boxes Strategy?

Tags: strategy, dots-and-boxes

What would be the strategy for the game [Boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_and_Boxes)? (Boxes is the game in which players connect dots on a grid and whoever encloses a box gets a point, along with an extra turn, until all lines are made)

Comment: Elwyn Berlekamp has written a whole [book](http://www.amazon.com/The-Dots-Boxes-Game-Sophisticated/dp/1568811292) on the subject.  It is a surprisingly deep game, given how simple it seems.

Comment: How is this a puzzle?

Comment: @Miniman - I see it as a question of game theory, too, instead of a puzzle.

Comment: @wbogacz: Some games of that general flavor (e.g Bridg-It) may be regarded as puzzles, in that a relatively simple 100%-winning strategy exists for a particular player and the puzzle is to find it.  Boxes doesn't happen to fall into that category, though I don't think that's intuitively obvious.  In a sense, the question is "Can this game be viewed as a puzzle"; the answer is "Not in general; some situations might reasonably be viewed as puzzles [e.g. "In this situation, the next player has one guaranteed-winning move; find it."], though most are probably not very interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game Boxes is another form of the game "Dots and Lines" or "Dots and Boxes", where the strategy is understood as a game of early control. The idea is to force the opponent into a condition to draw the third line into a long chain of near-complete boxes, where the ability to complete boxes with the fourth side yourself in a repetitive, connective manner is possible.

Strategy can better be explained on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_and_Boxes#Strategy), but in general terms details the use of a strategic sacrifice to the opponent to get to collect a few box wins, but be placed into a position to yield much greater returns for yourself because the last required move closes a third side into a long open chain.